What techniques can be used to detect chiral hydrogen bonds?
Hydrogen bonds, being weaker than primary chemical bonds, can eventually not be detected and measured with traditional techniques used for measuring on chiral molecules. What other physical techniques can be used for detecting or measuring chiral hydrogen bonds?
The chiral hydrogen bond can be imagined as forming chiral structures of molecules that can be non chiral as single molecules.
